# Send and receive to/from a UDP socket python3.4

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

i have these lines of code for sending and receving from a UDP socket in python3.4, in which i want to send a file from a user to the other.
This is the server side code:

```
...
data = file.read(1024)
n = int(fileSize / 1024) + 1
for i in range(n):
    if(self.sock.sendto(data.encode(), ('127.0.0.1',int(self.nextUserPort)))):
        print ("Sending ...")
        data = file.read(1024)
print ("File has been Sent Completely!!!")
self.sock.sendto("END#".encode(), ('127.0.0.1',int(self.nextUserPort)))
```

And this is the client side code:

```
....
d = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
data = d[0].decode()
addr = d[1]
try:
    while (data.strip().find("END#") != 0) :
        file.write(data.decode())
        time1 = time.time()
        data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
        time2 = time.time()
        print ("download speed is "+ str(1.0/(time2-time1))+" kbps")
    print ("File Downloaded Completely!!!!!")
except socket.timeout :
    file.close()
    self.sock.close()
```

But when i run the code i get the below error for the line `f(self.sock.sendto(data.encode(), ('127.0.0.1',int(self.nextUserPort))))`:

`AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

And when i remove the `encode` i get another error that when i searched it i got that i must encode it in `python3.4`.

Comment: When you create `file`, you should open it in either binary or text mode depending on how you plan to use it.  Sounds like binary mode. e.g. `with open('foo.bin', 'rb') as file: data = file.read(1024)`.

Comment: What was the other error?

Comment: You realize this code will only work if the server and client are on the same machine, and even then it's not really guaranteed, right?

Comment: Actually it is quite unlikely that the file will be transmitted correctly even on the same machine. `self.sock.sendto()` won't block and the kernel will happily discard packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is telling you what the problem is:

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

And as it happens you want to send bytes, so no need to convert anything in this line.

`"END#".encode()` can be directly written as `b"END#"`.

Unrelated to your question: You might want use a TCP socket or give the transfer some logic to cope with reordered, lost and duplicated packages.

Comment: I changed my code to this client and server codes [this](http://pastebin.com/Q58u5J7s) but i got this error : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 22: invalid start byte`.NOTE: i wnat to send an mp4 file

Comment: Then don't "decode" at all: You want bytes, not strings.

Comment: When i removed all `decode` s, i got this error : `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface` for the line : `while (data.strip().find("END#") != 0) `

Comment: UDP does not send a stream, but frames. `b'END#'` will be in a frame of its own, so no need for `strip()` (DO NOT USE STRING OPERATIONS ON BYTES, it's binary data).